# Is it possible to load Firebase contingently from javascript on the client?

Tags: javascript, firebase

From inside a client-side javascript file, I would like to contingently load the firebase include.

For example (using something like Jquery/Zepto):

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js',
 dataType: 'script',
 cache: true, 
 success: function() {
  // callback on success

 }
}
```

I'm trying to lazy-load the javascript API.

But, I'm running into CORS restrictions.  I understand I can use the REST API - but I prefer the firebase client.

Comment: Is `.getScript()` any better?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not having any trouble running your code. Maybe you're trying to run it locally from a file:// url? As opposed to on a page hosted by a server (e.g. localhost)?

Comment: Works like a charm in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/frankvanpuffelen/FfL4u/

Comment: Strange: when I change your fiddle to use Zepto (http://jsfiddle.net/FfL4u/1/) it raises a CORS error in the console and doesn't load.  When I switch it back to JQuery, it works fine